# Does Commander Chakotay have a first name?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In all of the episodes of Star Trek: Voyager that I've seen, I've never heard anyone call Commander Chakotay by any other name.  This includes formal and informal settings.  Does he have an official first/last name, or is Chakotay his full name like it is for Data?

Comment: I posted this from my phone. Feel free to edit it.

Comment: It’s Geoff. Geoff Chakotay.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - See my answer below. Word of God is that it's 'Fred Chakotay'.

Comment: His friends call him "Cha". Or sometimes Mr. Kotay.

Comment: @Richard: Robert Beltran may be your god, sir, but he is not... actually, excellent choice.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Chakotay is a mononym

Robert Beltran (the actor who portrays Chakotay on Star Trek Voyager) was asked this question in a [fan interview session](http://web.archive.org/web/20091001035540/http://www.startrek.com/startrek/view/community/chat/archive/transcript/1210.html). Although his reply seems mischievous, his ***lack*** of a genuine response strongly implies that his character only has one name.

> **Interviewer :** *What is Chakotay's first name in the Voyager series?*
>
> **Beltran :** ***Fred.***

---

The idea of him having a singular name is borne out by his gravestone in [VOY: Endgame, Part I](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Endgame_(episode)),

[image: http://www.startrek.com/legacy_media/images/200303/voy-271-admiral-janeway-visits/320x240.jpg]

his personnel file on the Valjean in [VOY: Caretaker](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Caretaker_(episode))

[image]

The crew manifest seen in [VOY: The Killing Game](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Killing_Game_(episode))

[image]

and his entry on the official [StarTrek.com website](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/chakotay)

[image]

Comment: For the record, his alias (Amol Kotay) has a first name. It's Amol.

Comment: With the placement of the quote from the interview, and the wording of the comment preceding the picture from "Endgame", I actually expected the tombstone to say "Fred Chakotay".

Comment: @RDFozz - Better?

Comment: Actually, yes. Note that I wasn't trying to saying there was necessarily anything wrong with the previous wording; just that, I read it differently than you intended. To be honest, I mentioned it because it amused me. All that said - thanks!

Answer (score 39):

Chakotay is his full name.  As I understand it, the Native American tribes never developed the custom of a family name (at least not before being conquered by Europeans). [His father](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Kolopak) was a traditionalist.

Source: [FEDERATION BIOGRAPHICAL DATABASE FILE: Chakotay](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/chakotay) at  [startrek.com](http://www.startrek.com)

Comment: It's also worth noting that even at Memory Beta, which includes non-canon sources (like novels), he still doesn't more of a name than Chakotay.  It's not clear if there is a given name or surname, or just one name.

Comment: @TangoOversway, if there's only one name, then by definition it can't be a surname. :)

Comment: In-universe this is probably correct. Out-of-universe, it is wildly inaccurate to make almost any claims about "Native American tribes" in general. The natives of pre-Columbian America ranged from the Inuit to the Fuegians and had many different naming customs. The Mayans, for example, did use family names as surnames.

Comment: The gravestone in the alternate timeline of the episode "End Game" (part 1) also has only "Chakotay" written on it.

Comment: I suppose his full name might be "Chakotay, son of Kolopak", or "Chakotay Kolopakson", just as Worf is referred to as "Worf, son of Mogh".